Statistics on reasons for delayed bags
After my checked luggage has been delayed for a third time in only a month, I am wondering if the problem lies with me. Are there any statistics on reasons for bags being delayed that I can consult, to reduce the risk of this happening again?
As I understand, about 3 % of all checked luggage is mishandled, out of which about 80 % are delays. Statistically speaking, the probability that bags would be delayed three times in a row, is 0.0013824 %, or once in every 72338 times.
First time: Flight with KLM from ICN - AMS - ARN. Some staff told me the bags (three hard case bags and one box) were not put on the flight from ICN, other staff told me the bags were not put on the flight from AMS. Bags were located within 24 hours, and returned to me after nine days. Baggage tags intact.
Second time: Flight with KLM from ARN - AMS - GVA. Flight cancellation caused a rebooking on Lufthansa from ARN - MUC - ZRH - GVA. This meant a change from Skyteam to Star Alliance, which perhaps played a role? However, they had about five hours at ARN airport to reroute it correctly. Bag (one hardcase) was located within 12 hours at ARN, and returned to me the following day. Baggage tag intact.
Third time: Flight with KLM from ARN - AMS - GVA. All the flights went as planned, and there was ample connection time in AMS. Bag is yet to be located after 48 hours.

Do you correctly remove the old tags (even the tiny ones they stick on other places of the bag) before a new flight? How tight were the connections? Any special in the bags which may cause additional scrutiny?

The common denominator here is (obviously) a transfer at Amsterdam to/from a KLM flight to Stockholm. It seems very plausible that some quirk of KLM's ground-handling operation means this route has mishandling statistics that are far worse than average (e.g. there are staffing issues at a particular time of day; other flights at a similar time are 'higher priority'; the flights typically use a set of gates that have substandard baggage handling infrastructure; etc.)

You have my sympathies!  Anyone who thinks this isn't a big deal should spend 2.5 days in the same underwear.  :|

I recently flew BHX - AMS - WAW on KLM.  My bag was lost.  It was delivered to my hotel the next day.  A few days later on the return flights, the same bag was lost.  It was delivered to my house 3 days later.  It was an American Tourister good quality bag and I am always careful to remove old tags.

@Kingsley For that reason, I always carry some emergency wear in hand carry.


Are there any statistics on reasons for bags being delayed that I can consult, to reduce the risk of this happening again?

Yes e.g. from skycop.com:

SITA’s report on 2023 luggage irregularities shows the reasons and their ratios:

Transfer mishandling – 46%;
Failure to load – 16%;
Ticketing error/bag/switch/security/other – 14%;
Airport/customs/weather/space-weight restrictions – 8%;
Loading error – 8%;
Arrival mishandling – 4%;
Tagged error – 4%.


Note that one can add some tracker e.g. Apple AirTag in one's suitcase to better understand what's going when a luggage is lost/delayed. The last time it happened to me, my Apple AirTag showed me that the airport employee was telling me some random BS about my delayed bag. (That's why I always laugh at the "did you ask the airline/customer supports/etc." comments that I keep reading on this site. Many airport/airline employees/contractors are clueless or just don't care about your situation/belongings.)

This tracks my experience. I have never had a delayed/lost bag on a direct flight, and the majority of my delayed/lost bags have been when interlining.

OTOH you must speak with airline. Sometime they know where baggage is, and sometime they may tell you that it is arrived, so you can quickly check if an other passenger took your baggage. Else: I agree, they tend to blame other airports. But also with an AirTag you must speak with them, and you need some report for insurance. -- Some staff is not great, but there are staff which can move mountains if one is polite.

Even with air tags you still need to file a lost luggage report and use the airline's tracking system. You can't just drive up to the air tag location, knock at the door and ask for your bag. Even more so if your bags happen to be in a different continent when you are.

@GiacomoCatenazzi The advantage of an AirTag is that you know, basically as soon as you’ve arrived, that your bag did not come with you. You can then spend your time filling out the report, rather than forlornly waiting by the carousel as everyone else’s bags are delivered.

@Sneftel: yeah, and I use it (so you know when baggage are put in carousel with some minutes of advantage. But also it is useful to help staff in case of missing baggage: you can tell in which airport it is (else staff just blames a random airport, which speed up things). More you can help staff, more help you can get from them.
